# Java - Can you write to 2 files from the 1 java class?

Tags: java, file

I am writing data to a `.dat` file. The data consists of `18000 tests` ran every minute and the file consists of all of these tests for 24 hours and a new file is created.

Along with the `.dat` file I have to create a `.idx` file which will take out the data for the start of each our and print and save it.

I am unsure as to whether I can create the `.dat` file and `.idx` file in the one class or do  I have to create 2 separate classes for each file?

Comment: That's rather vague. However I would advise you to try whatever approach seems the more intuitive to you, and refactor it if you realize it is impractical. Most modern Java IDEs offer powerful refactoring tools that should make it easy.

Comment: other than performance issues , i think yes you can

Comment: I was just trying to make it short and sweet, basically I have a `.dat` file that prints 5 pieces of data for every test that is ran `18000` times a minute for a whole day. I have to the make a `.idx` file to take the results at the start of every hour and print them up. I am wondering if it will easier to have it all in the one java class or have 2 separate classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class FileWriterExample {
    FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter(new File(path1));
    FileWriter writer2 = new FileWriter(new File(path2));

    //You can write to any of those indiferently
    //just remember to close them
    try {

    }finally{
        if(writer1 != null){
            writer1.flush();
            writer1.close();
        }
        if(writer2 != null){
            writer2.flush();
            writer2.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't fully understand the problem you're trying to solve, however:

- You certainly can write to two separate files from within the same class.
- If your features indicate classes with particular responsibilities then it may be worth separating them (and putting the file handling in the relevant class). For instance, it seems that you have an indexer which may well be a separate instance that takes the raw data to produce and write the index.
- Indeed, you may even have a `DataProducer` and a `DataIndexer` class to produce the relevant output and a `DataWriter` that manages the file output.
- Finally, if this is a large and time consuming activity, separation of the "heavy work" into smaller units will allow it to be distributed (say in a grid, space, cloud) to promote parallel processing. The indexer threads may be separately clustered.

All that said, I'd agree with @SirDarius's comment and get it going first then refactor to isolate the core work to make it efficient.

Answer (score 0):

> I am unsure as to whether I can create the .dat file and .idx file in
>   the one class or do I have to create 2 separate classes for each file?

This seems to be a common thing people are unsure about, surprisingly. But a class is just a vehicle to think about programming tasks in a particulary way, you can assume that it only exists in your head. Just as you can use multiple strings, numbers and whatever in your class, so you can use as many files as you want.

Also, think of it like this: How should a file "know" from which class it is used? And why, even if this was possible, should someone set up things in such a way that it is impossible to use 2 files from the same class?